# const function with functor modifying object

Tags: c++, constants, functor

If we consider the following method, I had the impression that `bar` can not modify `this` (i.e. its instance of `Foo`).

```
struct Foo {
  int i;
  // var shall not modify the respective instance of Foo, thus "const"
  void bar(std::function<void(int)> func) const {
    func(3);
  } 
};
```

However, the following is possible:

```
void anothermethod() {
  Foo f;
  f.bar([&](int x){f.i = 3;}); // modify Foo.i "within" Foo::bar const. Dangerous?
}
```

I see that the method `bar` is not "directly" modifying the value `i` of its instance, but its doing so "indirectly" via the given parameter `func`.

So here my question: Is it dangerous to do such things (i.e. passing a function that modifies the object into a `const` method of the respective object)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bar` didn't modify `i`, your lambda did.

Essentially you grabbed a reference to `i` from outside the class and stuffed that into the lambda.  Then you called `bar`.  `bar` made no mention of the members of itself, it only called some arbitrary (non-member, so the const-ness of `bar` is irrelevant) function that it was provided.

The flaw you have here is that one can get a hold of a reference to the `i` member from outside the struct.  Which means that anybody else can fiddle with `i`.  Make `i` private and see how well the above works for you.